Why is the mean higher than the median and the mode in a right skewed distribution?
If the distribution has a much higher frequency on the left side where the mode resides compared to the right side, then shouldn't the mean be about the same as the mode?

The rules about the position of the mean in relation to the median and the mode with regards to the skewness of a distribution, although frequently taught, fail quite often. I recommend reading the following article: https://web.archive.org/web/20160220181456/http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v13n2/vonhippel.html

Not at all.
Consider, as a very basic example the discrete distribution $\{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3\}$.
This has a mode of $1$, a median of $1$ but a mean greater than $1$.
Now consider the distribution $\{1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3\}$.
This has a mean less than $3$ but the mode and median are both $3$.
Indeed, comparing the mean to the median is a very nice way to quickly determine if the distribution has a skew.

But is what you said always true?
Consider the distribution {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4}.
The median and mode are both 1, while the mean is approximately 0.96;. The mean is less than the median and the mode, in spite of the distribution being skewed to the right.

Just because the distribution looks skewed to the right does not mean that this is actually the case. You can measure skew with a number. Calculate it for this distribution and see...

Consider the dataset $\mathcal{D} = \{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1, 5\}$. Computing the skewness using R we obtain $2.428844$, so it is right-skewed. However, the median is $1$ and the mean is $0.8461538$ ; the distribution is bimodal with modes $0$ and $1$.
Violations to this rule of thumb are common when the distribution is discrete or multimodal. If the distribution is continuous, but one tail is very long and the other one is very heavy, the mean will lie towards the heavier side, but since skewness is defined as
$$ \gamma = \mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \right)^3 \right] $$
extreme values in the longer tail will be cubed, making the distribution more skewed towards the other side.
The article https://web.archive.org/web/20160220181456/http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v13n2/vonhippel.html shows an example with real life data (Figure 3) and discusses this topic in more depth.

Thanks, very helpful answer.
What do you mean by "extreme values in the longer tail will be cubed"?

Perhaps this is easier to observe by noting that the formula for sample skewness is given by $\dfrac{\frac{1}{n} \sum (x_i - \overline{x})^3 }{ \left[  \frac{1}{n} \sum (x_i - \overline{x} )^2 \right]^{3/2} }$. Extreme values in the longer tail will be cubed, making the skewness more pronounced. Similarly, for theoretical skewness a longer tail means that there are more extreme values distant from $\mu$. When scaled by $\sigma$ and cubed, this will mean that a r.v. with longer tail will have a more pronounced skew.
